# Which locator is best to use in Selenium webdriver script, if id and name are unavailable?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie, and have to write a script for an element which is neither having ID or name. What should I use to get best results without any re-checks required?

Comment: You'll have to show the HTML. It's impossible to say what would be the best without seeing it.

Comment: There are many ways. Look at [By](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the element you are looking to identify,

1. if its a link you can use "linkText" or "partialLinkText"
2. for identifying using Tag Name use "tagName"
3. if there is unique class use "className"

if you are unable to find any of the above search the element using firepath (a Firefox Extension) but before using xpath get to know about different types of xpath to use.